# Webform submissions to 3rd party API with Refresher Authentication token

Tags: 8, webforms

How can you send the submitted information in a webform to a 3rd party API?

I have read this: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-programmatically-create-and-update-a-submission

But it looks this recipe is more about updating a submission rather that doing requests.

Any help?

**Note**:

I realized I can use handlers for submission, but need to use a refresh authentication token for submission. Are there any hooks for that?

I'm looking for hooks grab the data submitted from a specific form, then creates a POST request to create an access code and finally makes a POST request for a 3rd party API.

Using Zoho CRM API

Comment: You are going to want to write your own webform handler in a custom module.

Comment: @RyanHartman I thought this will be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this article creating a extension of a post handler to target specific webforms on submission.

https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/drupal-8-how-to-extending-a-webform-remote-post-handler

Code: https://github.com/chapter-three/drupal-hook-webform-handler-invoke-alter-example/blob/master/snippet.php

This is a very hard-coded solution, so I might think this might be a good idea to create a contrib module to extend the post request handler with multiple submissions.